# Object referenced by many, without own property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that is referenced by many other classes:

```
class Foo
{
    // Some properties
}

class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I can map this relationship on the `Bar` end:

```
class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        References(b => b.Foo).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

This works when I am deleting a `Bar` object but I am getting foreign key conflicts if I try and delete a `Foo` object. I understand this is because NHibernate doesn't know that there are `Bar`s relying on it, so happily tries to delete the `Foo` and not the `Bar`s.

I know I can do something along the lines of:

```
class Foo
{
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    // some properties
}

class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        HasMany(f => f.Bars)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphans();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to map `Foo` so that it knows about the inverse many-to-one relationship without adding a property to `Foo`? I don't really want to add a collection to `Foo` for each type of object referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have correctly understood your aim, and I fear the answer is you cannot do that easily.

You may try using [IInterceptor or event](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html) combined with some analysis of the meta-model NHibernate has generated from your mapping (see `ISessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata`), but this would probably requires a bunch of work hours.